# Pesquisa em duas tabelas com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho a seguinte situação:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao selecionar uma `marca` na `tabela` compatibilidade, quero Listar todos os produtos da tabela Produto, cujo código é igual ao código da marca selecionada.

**Exemplo:** ao selecionar **Toyota** deve listar **Cabine**, **Farol** e **Roda** e ao selecionar **Mazda** deve retornar somente **Cabine**

Fiz o seguinte:

```
$marca = $this->input->post('marca');
$marca = explode(',', $marca);    
$query = array();
if (count($marcas) > 0) 
{
    $i = 0;         
    foreach ($comp as $row) 
    {
        $i++;
        if ($row !== "") 
        {
            if ($row !== "0") 
            {
                $query[] = $row;
                $this->db->where_in('marca', $query);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Mas com este código só consigo pegar os produtos com a seguinte tabela:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso programar para fazer a relação das duas tabelas através do campo `codigo`?

Comment: e ai a solução te ajudou?

Comment: Boas, A solução foi muito útil, mas não consegui fazer o que esperava no meu script, assim mudei a composição das tabelas para facilitar ainda mais a minha pesquisa... em vez de usar duas tabelas vou usar uma tabela... e usar a função json_decode

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar o seu problema é simples, o código abaixo exemplifica o que precisa codificar:

```
$this->db
     ->from('compatibilidade')
     ->join('produto', 'compatibilidade.codigo=produto.codigo')
     ->where('compatibilidade.marca', $marca)
     ->select('produto.*, compatibilidade.marca')
     ->get()
     ->result_array();
```

Algumas observações pode melhorar o desempenho dessa `SQL`

- Crie um indice nos campos `codigo` das duas tabelas, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Crie um indice no campo `marca`

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não sei bem a sua regra de negócio, como está sua programação poderia até criar um relação nos dois campos, mas, o que foi exemplificado já basta para solucionar seu problema.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class)</sub>